# How to stop page from redirecting without event in Javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, dom-events

I have an ajax plugin with a load of ajax files from a tag. When user clicks on it I don't see it to redirecting to the other page. Although we stop redirecting page using events like:

```
$(button).click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

I want a function that stop page from redirecting without events.

```
function functionName() {
   functiontostopredirect(); // I need a function like this.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `return false` from that function:

```
function functionName() {
   return functiontostopredirect(); // i need a function like this.
}
functiontostopredirect(){ return false;}
```

Answer (score 0):

add return false , onclick of button:

```
<button type="submit" onclick="return false;">Submit</button>
```

Comment: but i attach a function to it **onclick="$(this).ajaxLoad();"**

Comment: means you want to call ajax on button click?

Comment: yeah i wan to load file. without redirecting